# Webhook script langages for Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I look forward to develop a script for Google Assistant.
In what languages could I develop the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any language you want!

Well, pretty much. It has to meet two criteria, but most programming languages do these days:

1. It needs to be able to be accessed via HTTPS on the public web.
2. It needs to be able to understand a JSON HTTP body that is sent to it and reply with a JSON encoded response.

Google provides [a library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) if you are developing with JavaScript/node.js, but those just provide programmatic ways to handle the HTTP body contents and generate the response.

But you can certainly get the information you want from the [content sent to your webhook](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/webhook) and then reply using the response format.